# Uploading to documentDB is missing inner JSON members of complex objects

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am uploading data to the documentDB using the following code:

```
   private static async Task UploadEntry(OptimizationData entry)
    {
        try
        {
            string endpointUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DocumentDBEndpointURL");
            string authorizationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DocumentDBAuthKey");
            string databaseId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DocumentDBDatabaseId");
            string collectionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CollectionName");

            using (DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey))
            {
                DocumentCollection documentCollection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery("dbs/" + databaseId).Where(c => c.Id == collectionName).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

                if (documentCollection != null)
                {
                    await client.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/" + databaseId + "/colls/" + documentCollection.Id, entry);
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            //Ignored
        }

    }
```

Now my objects are of these types:

```
 public class OptimizationData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<DateTime,OptimizationEntry> Optimization;
}
```

And Optimization Entry looks like this:

```
   [DataContract]
   public class OptimizationEntry 
   {
    [DataMember]
    public decimal price{ get; set; }
    public decimal optimalPrice { get; set; }         
    public decimal weight { get; set; }
   }
```

The problem is, when I look into my document explorer on azure's portal, the inner items of the dictionary are missing. I.e., it has datetime, and the first item (price) but not optimialPrice and Weight

```
"Optimization": {
"2016-01-27T21:00:00": {
  "price": 179.482711791992
},
"2016-01-27T22:00:00": {
  "price": 196.533660888672
},

 ....
```

Is there a way I'm supposed to insert the document so that the inner objects are not missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question for possible future people who need help, the reason they were not showing was that the OptimizationEntry only had "price" as [DataMember] so that it could be serialized, the other two did not. Therefore JSON serialization did not include them in the upload.

Comment: you can also use JSON.NET attributes. [JsonProperty(PropertyName="foo")] if you want to control how the properties are serialized / deserialized/